# How to echo a 12x12 grid filled with times tables

Tags: php, math

I need to create a grid that is 12x12.
It needs to be filled in with times tables, you know? 1 times 1 is one, 2 times 1 is two and so on...

EXAMPLE: http://rigsamarole.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/times-table-12x12.gif

I tried making a table and defining $x to 1 and $y to 1 and multiplying them. I then wrapped it in a while loop.

It gave me the answer, but how would I put this in a table?

How would I format this using PHP and HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a table like this :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { ?>
                <th><?php echo $i; ?></th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php for($j=1; $j<=12; $j++) { ?>
                <td><?php echo $i*$j; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```